# A "Decadent" Cheesecake?

Tags: adjectives, food

Is the adjective *"decadent"* suitable to be used in the context *"a decadent cheesecake"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will turn your [prose purple](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/purple+prose), but sure.

Comment: Is it appropriate to use purple prose when describing a product on a website?

Comment: This is veering into the realm of opinion, but here's mine: only if you're writing ad copy.

Comment: I don't think this is a particularly purple usage.   The adjective _decadent_ is particularly used with rich and fatty foodstuffs, like creme, fine chocolate, caviar, foie gras, etc.

Comment: @Billare, I agree that it's commonly used -- but if you consider its primary meaning, as in the phrase "the decadence of Rome," it seems pretty hyperbolic, don't you think? I mean, Nero wasn't just eating cheesecake.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's suitable and common.  It's lost most of its punch through over-use, but it won't look odd at all.

Comment: Can you suggest a better adjective?

Comment: It depends on what you want to communicate about the cheesecake.

Comment: Well, since its describing a product, anything good about it.

Comment: EPICurean will catch both the hi- and lo-brow elements of your audience

Comment: That's just the thing: if you have nothing in particular to say about it, you can write "decadent" which is used mostly to connote luxury.  But if you have something in particular to communicate about the product, e.g. "berry/light/tiramisu/large/traditional cheesecake", I would say that and drop the "decadent".

Comment: Other suitable near-content-free patter: elegant, sinful, delightful, delicious.

Comment: @JeffSahol It's a great word but is it not under-used?

Comment: "Epicurean" is not commonly used but it's well-known; certainly most would recognize it.  Of course Jeff's choice of spelling highlights the modern meaning 'great, amazing' of epic; it's eye-catching but also less elegant.  (It might work for you, depending on your audience.)

Comment: @Proffesor, Charles has spelled out what I meant to convey: 'decadent' is perfectly grammatical, but it means almost nothing when applied to 'cheesecake.' It's a filler word. If you've tasted the cheesecake, do your audience a favor and tell them whether it's light or dense, whether it has a creamy or a fluffy texture. But if you haven't tasted it... well, 'decadent' is as good a filler as any. (Though I would probably go for 'luscious.')

Comment: @Proffesor In English: *Decadent* isn't totally meaningless. In the context of a cheesecake it implies *extravagantly luxurious* (i.e. - full of tasty sugar & fat, but you don't want to actually say that). But in the modern post-economic-crisis world it's probably best not to overplay such attributes. Now a *spartan, frugal* cheesecake - that might sell!

Comment: I agree that "decadent" isn't meaningless when applied to a cheesecake. I would expect a cheesecake thus described to be full-fat, for example, and probably New York style, i.e. dense and rich, rather than light & fluffy. (I would *not* use this adjective for a low-calorie cheesecake.)

Comment: @Martha: Right, it has some meaning -- along the lines of "sinful" but not quite as strong.  But generally it's used (in this context) more for its _connotation_ than its _denotation_.

Answer (score 1):

In advertising slang, this usage is common, and it means—well, that is the problem with advertising. It doesn't mean anything specific; it just wants to evoke images of a decadent lifestyle, with lots of delicious food.

This does not belong in any serious text, though, where the word *decadent* is mostly limited to describing (groups of) people or habits straying from the right path, whatever that may be.